# How to transfer files between AWS s3 and AWS ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS ec2 instance.  On this instance I'm resulting some files. These operations are done by user data.

Now I want to store those files on s3 by writing code in user data itself.

- So how can I store those files on s3?
- Have any tutorials on it?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 78):

Using the most recent AWS CLI (http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) you can use the following commands to copy files from your Ec2 Instance or even you local machine to S3 storage.

```
aws s3 cp myfolder s3://mybucket/myfolder --recursive
```

You'll then get something like:

```
upload: myfolder/file1.txt to s3://mybucket/myfolder/file1.txt 
upload: myfolder/subfolder/file1.txt to s3://mybucket/myfolder/subfolder/file1.txt
```

If this is your first usage of the `aws` CLI tool then you'll need to run:

`aws configure`

This will ask you to enter your access key & secret along with specifying a default region.

Comment: aws cli is much better than s3cmd.

Comment: @ajtrichards Is there any way to provide access key&secret using command line argument?

Comment: @EmptyData you could use the `--profile PROFILE_NAME` flag to indicate which set of credentials to use? If you've setup multiple AWS profiles on your command line that is.

Comment: It's an even better idea to use IAM roles at the instance level so that you don't need to store credentials on the server. [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html)

Comment: 100% you should use IAM roles when in EC2 to manage creds and access permissions.

Comment: Keep in mind that, this comman copies the contents of the folder to S3 bucket's folder, not the folder iteself.

Comment: to use the aws s3 cp command, you must have the aws credentials in place namely in ~/.aws/credentials file. they look like this:
[default]
aws_access_key_id =...
aws_secret_access_key = ...

Answer (score 32):

There are a number of ways to send files to S3. I've listed them below along with installation and documentation where relevant.

- **S3CMD**: (http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) You can install this on debian/ubuntu easily via apt-get install s3cmd, then run from command line. You could incorporate this into a bash script or your program.
- **S3FS**: (http://www.pophams.com/blog/howto-setups3fsonubuntu1104x64 and https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/InstallationNotes) ... This mounts an s3 bucket, so that it looks just like a local disk. It takes a little more effort to setup, but once the disk is mounted, you don't need to do anything special to get the files in your bucket.
- If you use a CMS (lets use Drupal as an example) you may have the option of **using a module** to handle access to your bucket eg http://drupal.org/project/storage_api
- Finally, you can use **programming language implementations** to handle all the logical yourself, for PHP you can start with this http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class and see documentation here http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation

An example of the PHP implementation:

```
<?php

    // Simple PUT:
    if (S3::putObject(S3::inputFile($file), $bucket, $uri, S3::ACL_PRIVATE)) {
        echo "File uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Failed to upload file.";
    }

?>
```

An example of s3cmd:

```
s3cmd put my.file s3://bucket-url/my.file
```

## Edit

Another option worth mention is the AWS CLI http://aws.amazon.com/cli/
This is widely available, for example it's already included on AmazonLinux and can be downloaded via Python (which is installed on many systems including linux and windows).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html

> Available commands, cp ls mb mv rb rm sync website

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/index.html for interacting with S3

Comment: Great ans friend .. was just looking for this :)

Answer (score 12):

Install **s3cmd** Package as:

```
yum install s3cmd
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install s3cmd
```

depending on your OS. Then copy data with this:

```
s3cmd get s3://tecadmin/file.txt
```

also `ls` can list the files.

For more detils see [this](http://tecadmin.net/install-s3cmd-manage-amazon-s3-buckets/#)

Answer (score 10):

I'm using [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) to store nightly exported database backup files from my ec2 instance.  After configuration of s3cmd, which you can read about at their site, you can then run a command like:

`s3cmd put ./myfile s3://mybucket`

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 6):

Use `s3cmd` for that:

```
s3cmd get s3://AWS_S3_Bucket/dir/file
```

See how to install s3cmd [here](http://kb.site5.com/shell-access-ssh/how-to-setup-and-configure-the-s3cmd-tool-for-amazon-s3/):

This works for me...

Answer (score 4):

All attempts to mount s3 as a pseudo filesystem are problematic. It's an object store, not a block device. 
If you must mount it because you have legacy code that must have local file paths, try goofys. It's about 50x faster than s3fs. https://github.com/kahing/goofys

s3cmd is a bit long in the tooth these days. The AWS cli is a better option these days. The syntax is a bit less convenient, but it's one less tool you need to keep around.

If you can stick to http access. It'll make you life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

On AWS CLI I have used the following command to copy zip file from EC2 instance to S3

```
aws s3 cp file-name.zip s3://bucket-name/
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best answer in general is in fact above, to use the `aws` command, but for the cases where you don't want to bother installing anything else, it's also worth mentioning that you can just download the file over HTTPS, e.g. open a browser and navigate to:

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/`*(bucketName)*`/`*(relativePath)*`/`*(fileName)*

That also means you could just use `wget` or `curl` to do transfer from shell prompts.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you need to copy from a new instance to s3.  First create a IAM role so you dont need to run aws configure and this should all work at launch time.  Second Install the cli and then define your copy job using aws cli in user data. Example below for Ubuntu 18. Assign the IAM role to your instance.

***Userdata:***

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update -y
apt install awscli -y
aws s3 cp *Path of data* s3://*destination bucket*  -recursive *--other options*
```

***To create an IAM role***
 1. Go to the IAM console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/
 2. In the left pane, select Roles then click Create role.
 3. For Select type of trusted entity, choose AWS service. Select EC2.
    Select Next: Permissions.
 4. For Attach permissions policies, choose the AWS managed policies
    that contain the required permissions or create a custom policy.
 5. Click Service Choose A service, type S3 in Find a service box, click
    S3, select actions (all or read + write and others you may need)
 6. Click on Resources, Select Resource (you can enter all resouces or
    limit to specific bucket with the ARN)
 7. Click Next: Review policy. Enter an Name and Description. Click
    Create policy.
 8. Return to Create Role page, click refresh, filter policy by name you
    assigned, select the policy.
 9. Click Next: Tags and then add any required tags
 10. On the Review page, enter a name and description for the role and
     click Create role.

***References***

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/amazon-s3-authenticated-bootstrapping-in-aws-cloudformation/
- https://optimalbi.com/aws-tips-and-tricks-moving-files-from-s3-to-ec2-instance/