# Load S3 data into a Windows EC2 server in AWS

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have a file in S3 that I would like to load in R, which runs on a Windows EC2 instance. How can I do this?

I have read similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910534/how-to-transfer-files-between-aws-s3-and-aws-ec2) , but they all refer to linux instances. Many thanks.

Comment: Looks like there are several packages to read S3 files... https://github.com/Gastrograph/RS3 and https://github.com/armstrtw/AWS.tools

Comment: Thanks. The first link states it does not work on windows.

Comment: You could give [aws.s3](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3) a try.